# Why does Parse work and Convert doesn't in C#?

Tags: c#, integer

I want to square every digit in `str` and concatenate it to `pow`.

I have this simple code:

```
string str = "1234";
string pow = "";

foreach(char c in str)
{
   pow += Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt32(c), 2);
}
```

It should return `14916` - instead it returns: `2401250026012704`

But if I use `int.Parse(c)`, it returns the correct number.

```
foreach(char c in str)
{
    int i = int.Parse(c.ToString());
    pow += Math.Pow(i, 2);
}
```

Why does `Parse` work and `Convert` doesn't?

Comment: You can use `Math.Pow(Char.GetNumericValue(c), 2)`. You should not compare apples with pears. Once you convert a `char` to `int` and then you parse a `String` to `int`. The rules are different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-7.0#system-convert-toint32(system-char)) of `Convert.ToInt32(char)`:

> The `ToInt32(Char)` method returns a 32-bit signed integer that represents the UTF-16 encoded code unit of the value argument.

Therefore, for example, the char `'1'` will be converted to the integer value `49`, as defined in the UTF-16 encoding: https://asecuritysite.com/coding/asc2.

---

An alternative approach to the `int.Parse(c.ToString())` example, would be `Char.GetNumericValue`:

```
foreach(char c in str)
{
   pow += Math.Pow(char.GetNumericValue(c), 2);
}
```

This converts the char to the numeric equivalent of that value.

Comment: You can also do `Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString()), 2)`

Comment: @Danial You could, but `Char.GetNumericValue` is more idiomatic than using an intermediate string.

Comment: `int result = c - '0';` is faster